# formula font size in xepersian

Tags: math-mode, fontsize, xepersian

I use xepersian package. The font size of the math formula is too smaller than the text. I have use `\DeclareMathSizes{16pt}{14pt}{10pt}{8pt}` but it doesn't change.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 24pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, inner=2cm, outer=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathcomp}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathSizes{24}{24.5}{22}{22}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=3]{BCompset}

\begin{document}
  در گرانش ثابت نیوتن بدون بعد ( در فضای $ d $ بعدی ) $ g=k^{d-2} G_{k} $ که معرف قدرت برهمکنش است با رفتن به انرژیهای پایین کاهش می‌یابد.
\end{document} `
```

Comment: Have you a minimal working example (MWE)?

Comment: @RomainPicot : I added MWE.

Comment: I've seen, unfortunetly I'm not on my computer and I've an older version of TL and can't compile. But with this MWE, other people will help you `:)`

Comment: I'm compiling it and producing this: http://i.imgur.com/ciFqCek.png . I see the math font the same size as the text. Do you have your distribution up to date? At least the relevant packages? (probably mathtools if that's the one changing the font size)

Comment: @MyUserIsThis : I edited it again. Would you please compile it another time ?

Answer (score 3):

I guess that your aim is to produce a document in a large font size, but `Scale=3` is the wrong way to do it, because this won't scale the math fonts.

You can use `extarticle`, that supports up to 20pt

```
\documentclass[20pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, inner=2cm, outer=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Scheherazade}

\begin{document}

  در گرانش ثابت نیوتن بدون بعد ( در فضای $ d $ بعدی ) $ g=k^{d-2} G_{k} $ که معرف قدرت برهمکنش است با رفتن به انرژیهای پایین کاهش می‌یابد.

\LARGE

  در گرانش ثابت نیوتن بدون بعد ( در فضای $ d $ بعدی ) $ g=k^{d-2} G_{k} $ که معرف قدرت برهمکنش است با رفتن به انرژیهای پایین کاهش می‌یابد.


\end{document}
```

You may still want to scale up the main font, but not by 3.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that was just an example. For the [Scale=1.7] or other, this problem occured. I found a problem. I should use \settextfont[Scale=1.7]{BCompset}
\DeclareMathSizes{12}{35}{14}{10} after the \usepackage{xepersian}.

Comment: In version 19.7 of xepersian package some command exist  that help you. please see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `\DeclareMathSizes{24}{24.5}{22}{22}`.
Because it doesn't accept  `24pt` and its default is `10pt`. Therefore `\DeclareMathSizes`
 does not work in this case (24pt).
You should use the `xepersian` package with these options:

```
\usepackage[%
fontsizescale=3,%
latinfontsizescale=2.4,%
mathfontsizescale=2.4%
]{xepersian}
```

**`Which in there`**:

The **fontsizescale** scale is for text font scale.

The **latinfontsizescale** is  for latin text font scale.

The **mathfontsizescale** is for math font scale.

So you have these `codes`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 24pt]{article}
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper, landscape, inner=2cm, outer=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathcomp}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{mathtools}

%\DeclareMathSizes{24}{24.5}{22}{22}

%\usepackage{xepersian}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[%
fontsizescale=3,%
latinfontsizescale=2.4,%
mathfontsizescale=2.4%
]{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}

\begin{document}
  در گرانش ثابت نیوتن بدون بعد ( در فضای $ d $ بعدی ) $ g=k^{d-2} G_{k} $ که معرف قدرت برهمکنش است با رفتن به انرژیهای پایین کاهش می‌یابد.
\end{document}
```

And you'll get this `output`:

[image]

Good luck.